# Listview fillup with adatper

Tags: android

I have created custom listview with baseadapter.
it's working fine. 
but I am calculating total amout when adatper is filliup via getview method.

My question is when I can find that adapter has completed his process of filling up listview?

When adapter called `getview()` method for last the record after that I want to broadcast message. How can   I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Adapter` does not fill `listview` completely. It will only fill views that are on the screen ( it also depends on **framework** cos companies like Samsung, Sony do change the android framework a lot)

The best you should do is call `Notifydatasetchanged` on adapter and then handle call after that.

Views and whatever adapter needs to call should be done by then

Can you please explain more what you want to achieve. You probably need to use the adapter data and not think about touching its **UI** part?

Comment: When I write this line listview.setAdatper(Adapter) after that I cannot detect when the process has complted of filling data in lsitview.

Comment: thats wat i am saying its a ui thing and getView can be called anytime you move the listview. the best approach is to call notifydatasetchanged after this line this will update ui on main thread and then using the data set that exists in the adapter you should send broadcast. Dont compare it with Windows which creates UI one time (in android getview would be called for each ui update on screen for listview)

Comment: Suppose I have txtTotalAmt. I have put totalAmt+=mogel.getAmount() in get view method. now I want to set totalAmt in txtTotalAmt. so When/Where I should write txtTotalAmt.setText(totalAmt+"")?

Comment: Dont put the totalAmt += model.getAmount() in getview method. Call listview.setadapter, then after this line call int totalAmt = adapter.getTotalAmount (put a method in adapter). Use this totalAmt to set your textview text. getView is wrong place to put this method

Comment: Confued.  then after this line call int totalAmt = adapter.getTotalAmount (put a method in adapter). Use this totalAmt to set your textview text. getView is wrong place to put this method    I have to add every amount in totalamount so "this line is compelsory  totalAmt += model.getAmount() "

Comment: create a method in your adapter class getTotalAmount(). After calling listView.setAdapter(adapter), call this method adapter.getTotalAmount(). In the getTotalAmount() function go through all of your data and calculate total amount. if you add code i can help you more. you can always get total amount from the data you set on adapter. Please read about fly weight pattern of listviews to make things more clear